# UITabBarControllerDelegate's method is not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I create programmatically a UITabBarController with more than 5 tabs (exactly 8 child view controllers).

My purpose is custom transition animation for tab changing. I setup a delegate for the UITabbarController and implement the method:

```
- (nullable id <UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController
            animationControllerForTransitionFromViewController:(UIViewController *)fromVC
                                              toViewController:(UIViewController *)toVC
```

When I select a tab by sending:

```
[tabbarController setSelectedIndex: 6];
```

delegate's method is not called.

Delegate's method is called properly when I send

```
[tabbarController setSelectedIndex: 3];
```

for example, i.e. for a visible tab.

One more remark: if currently selected view controller is in visible range 0..3 and next view is out of the visible range 0..3 delegate's method is still called. In case when currently selected view controller is out of  the visible range 0..3 and next view is out of the visible range 0..3 too delegate's method is not called. And I lose my custom transition animation. This is my problem.

I also tried to send

```
[tabbarController setSelectedViewController: someViewController];
```

instead of

```
[tabbarController setSelectedIndex: 6];
```

It doesn't work.

Comment: Are you sure the tab bar controller's `delegate` property is set?

Comment: Yes. I setup delegate. And delegate's method is called properly when I send  [tabbar setSelectedIndex: 3]; for example, i.e. for a visible tab.

Comment: How many tabs? 6? It's a 0 based index, so that shouldn't work (though it would crash).

Comment: tabs count is 8.

Comment: @RamilRamil try with `[[self tabBarController] setSelectedIndex:5];` for me works without problem

Comment: @ReinierMelian, tell me please how many tabs do you have? Equal or more than 6? delegate's method is called for any index?

Comment: Are the other tabs instantiated? Do they have any content?

Comment: @RamilRamil can you tell us the class definition of your `tabbar` property? what is it? a `UITabBar` or `UITabBarController`? check this image is my setup, and works http://imgur.com/a/axD8F

Comment: @brandonscript, yes all child viewcontrollers of the tabbar are initiated.

Comment: @ReinierMelian, it's my error, edited the question. thank you

Comment: @ReinierMelian, I create UITabbarController programmatically. Everything works fine, all tabs are selected. But delegate's method is called only for indexes in range 0..3.

Comment: But, with that many tabs, wouldn't you be pulling up the `moreNavigationController`? -  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbarcontroller/1621183-morenavigationcontroller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made tricky solution.

I collect all 8 view controllers in separated array. Call it **controllers**.

At start I fill **tabbarController.viewcontrollers** with first 5 items of **controllers**. Further there are 2 scenarios:

1. User wants to see a tab with **index** within **range 0..4**. There is nothing to do because we already set appropriate viewcontrollers into **tabbarController.viewcontrollers**.
2. User wants to see a tab with **index** out of the  **range 0..4**.  User wants to see the tab with index 6, for example. And currently selected tab has index 2, for example. In this case I select a number in range 0..4 which is unequal to currently selected tab index. For example 4. Further I replace **tabbarController.viewcontrollers[4]** with **controllers[6]**. After that I call

   ```
    [tabbarController setSelectedIndex: 4];
   ```

As result I see **controllers[6]** and delegate's method is called properly.

Answer (score 0):

You have too many tabs to use `selectedIndex`, as your other tabs are probably in the `moreNavigationController` even if the `moreNavigationController` is not displayed on the screen - meaning they should return `NSNotFound` when using `selectedIndex`.

You should use `selectedViewController` instead, [per iOS Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbarcontroller/1621172-selectedviewcontroller)

```
[tabbarController setSelectedViewController: yourIndexSixViewController];
```